# Styling contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, select, contact-form-7

I have made a contact form with contact form 7. Due to the styling of the theme, the selectbox does not work properly.

You cannot select multiple options and you can scroll in the select box instead of it expanding as a dropdown.

Can someone help me with this?

url: https://www.lghairdressers.nl/basis-opleiding/

Comment: You can design a much more compact form using the [Smart Grid layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), see this online [examples](https://youtu.be/snKSPByqbBM).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that the select field has `multiple=true`, and this is the [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) styling for multiple fields.

If you want to retain a dropdown list for a multiple select, you will need to convert your field using a JavaScript plugin such as a [HybridDropdown](https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/) field using the following script on your page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    let sel, hyd;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {  //instantiate on document ready.
      sel= document.querySelectorAll('.wpcf7-select');
      sel.forEach(function(){
        hyd = new HybridDropdown(this,{});
      })
    })
  })
  </script>
```